# How to properly integrate run Flask (app.py) using KapellaTemplate

Tags: python, templates, flask, dashboard

I would like to know how can I leverage free template from [Kapella-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template](https://github.com/TemplateWatch/Kapella-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template) using flask app.py. Appreciate help on this matter. Thank you.

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return flask.render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    port = 8000

    # Open a web browser pointing at the app.
    os.system("open http://localhost:{0}".format(port))

    # Set up the development server on port 8000.
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

The structure as follows

```
app.py
templates
 index.html
 css
 images
```

When I run app.py... the pages come out but without images..not in nice format
[image]

The template should look like below
[image]

Appreciate help. Thanks